# Getting Error while publishing ADFv2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have done the changes in the Azure data factory pipeline. Selected the "VSTS Git" option and trying to publish the changes it was working fine but now started getting below error message:

`Error while publishing: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined`

Retried by removing the changes but still getting same issue.

Comment: Can you clarify, you're selecting Get *after* making changes?  You should have selected the Git source before making changes.

Comment: Yes by keeping the "VSTS Git" I am making changes. The Validate All does not give error but when after Save All I am trying to publish getting the error.

Comment: Press F12, do you see any error in console?

Comment: If you change the source option *after* making changes, those changes are in a different pool from what you're trying to deploy.  So, you need to modify either the Git copy or the DF copy, then deploy.

Comment: Yes, after selecting Git option I am making changes but still same error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a broken resource in your collaberation branch which is causing the issue.
You can re-sync Git and Live mode by disconnecting and reconnecting Git. 
*Please note that you would lose the differences between the two.*

Hope this will help.